# Lost Gray On IsEnabled False

Tags: .net, wpf, foreground, isenabled

Once I set the TextBlock Foreground Property then I lost the gray on IsEnable=False on buttons and also lost the gray on ToolTip.

How can I set a the style for TextBlock foreground and not effect the IsEnable=False and ToolTip?

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semilight" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,1,0,1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource  BrushDarkDarkBlue}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place your `Foreground` setter in a `Trigger` that will only set the value if the `IsEnabled` property value is `true`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semilight" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,1,0,1" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushDarkDarkBlue}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When `IsEnabled` turns to `false`, the default (template / style) value will be set keeping this "graying out" effect.